# WebCrawler with recursion

Tags: java, recursion, web-crawler

So I am working on a webcrawler that is supposed to download all images, files, and webpages, and then recursively do the same for all webpages found. However, I seem to have a logic error.

```
    public class WebCrawler {

   private static String url;
   private static int maxCrawlDepth;
   private static String filePath;

   /* Recursive function that crawls all web pages found on a given web page.
    * This function also saves elements from the DownloadRepository to disk.
    */

  public static void crawling(WebPage webpage, int currentCrawlDepth, int maxCrawlDepth) {

     webpage.crawl(currentCrawlDepth);

     HashMap<String, WebPage> pages = webpage.getCrawledWebPages();

        if(currentCrawlDepth < maxCrawlDepth) {
           for(WebPage wp : pages.values()) {
              crawling(wp, currentCrawlDepth+1, maxCrawlDepth);
           }
        }
     }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      if(args.length != 3) {
         System.out.println("Must pass three parameters");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      url = "";
      maxCrawlDepth = 0;
      filePath = "";

      url = args[0];
      try {
         URL testUrl = new URL(url);
         URLConnection urlConnection = testUrl.openConnection();
         urlConnection.connect();
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         System.out.println("Not a valid URL");
         System.exit(0);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Could not open URL");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      try {
         maxCrawlDepth = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         System.out.println("Argument is not an int");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      filePath = args[2];
      File path = new File(filePath);
      if(!path.exists()) {
         System.out.println("File Path is invalid");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      WebPage webpage = new WebPage(url);
      crawling(webpage, 0, maxCrawlDepth);

      System.out.println("Web crawl is complete");
   }

}
```

the function crawl will parse the contents of a website storing any found images, files, or links into a hashmap, for example:

```
    public class WebPage implements WebElement {

   private static Elements images;
   private static Elements links;

   private HashMap<String, WebImage> webImages = new HashMap<String, WebImage>();
   private HashMap<String, WebPage> webPages = new HashMap<String, WebPage>();
   private HashMap<String, WebFile> files = new HashMap<String, WebFile>();

   private String url;

   public WebPage(String url) {
      this.url = url;
   }

   /* The crawl method parses the html on a given web page
    * and adds the elements of the web page to the Download
    * Repository.
    */
   public void crawl(int currentCrawlDepth) {

      System.out.print("Crawling " + url + " at crawl depth ");
      System.out.println(currentCrawlDepth + "\n");

      Document doc = null;

      try {
         HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Jsoup.connect(url);
         httpConnection.ignoreContentType(true);
         doc = httpConnection.get();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage()); 
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
         System.out.println(url + "is not a valid URL");
      }

      DownloadRepository downloadRepository = DownloadRepository.getInstance();

      if(doc != null) {
         images = doc.select("img");
         links = doc.select("a[href]");

         for(Element image : images) {
            String imageUrl = image.absUrl("src");
            if(!webImages.containsValue(image)) {
               WebImage webImage = new WebImage(imageUrl);
               webImages.put(imageUrl, webImage);
               downloadRepository.addElement(imageUrl, webImage);
               System.out.println("Added image at " + imageUrl);
            }
         }

         HttpConnection mimeConnection = null;
         Response mimeResponse = null;

         for(Element link: links) {
            String linkUrl = link.absUrl("href");
            linkUrl = linkUrl.trim();
            if(!linkUrl.contains("#")) {
               try {
                  mimeConnection = (HttpConnection) Jsoup.connect(linkUrl);
                  mimeConnection.ignoreContentType(true);
                  mimeConnection.ignoreHttpErrors(true);
                  mimeResponse = (Response) mimeConnection.execute();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                  System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
               }

               String contentType = null;
               if(mimeResponse != null) {
                  contentType = mimeResponse.contentType();
               }

               if(contentType == null) {
                  continue;
               }
               if(contentType.toString().equals("text/html")) {
                  if(!webPages.containsKey(linkUrl)) {
                     WebPage webPage = new WebPage(linkUrl);
                     webPages.put(linkUrl, webPage);
                     downloadRepository.addElement(linkUrl, webPage);
                     System.out.println("Added webPage at " + linkUrl);
                  }
               }
               else {
                  if(!files.containsValue(link)) {
                     WebFile webFile = new WebFile(linkUrl);
                     files.put(linkUrl, webFile);
                     downloadRepository.addElement(linkUrl, webFile);
                     System.out.println("Added file at " + linkUrl);
                  }
               }

            }
         }

      }

      System.out.print("\nFinished crawling " + url + " at crawl depth ");
      System.out.println(currentCrawlDepth + "\n");
   }

   public HashMap<String, WebImage> getImages() {
      return webImages;
   }

   public HashMap<String, WebPage> getCrawledWebPages() {
      return webPages;
   }

   public HashMap<String, WebFile> getFiles() {
      return files;
   }

   public String getUrl() {
      return url;
   }

   @Override
   public void saveToDisk(String filePath) {
      System.out.println(filePath);
   }
}
```

The point of using a hashmap is to ensure that I do not parse the same website more than once. The error seems to be with my recursion. What is the issue?

Here is also some sample output for starting the crawl at http://www.google.com

```
Crawling https://www.google.com/ at crawl depth 0

Added webPage at http://www.google.com/intl/en/options/
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/ads/
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/services/
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/about.html
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/
Finished crawling https://www.google.com/ at crawl depth 0

Crawling https://www.google.com/services/ at crawl depth 1

Added webPage at http://www.google.com/intl/en/enterprise/apps/business/?utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=en&utm_source=us-en-et-nelson_bizsol
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/services/sitemap.html
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/
Finished crawling https://www.google.com/services/ at crawl depth 1

**Crawling https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/ at crawl depth 2**

Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/faq/
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/technologies/
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/
Added webPage at https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/

Finished crawling https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/ at crawl depth 2

**Crawling https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/ at crawl depth 3**
```

Notice that it parses http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/ twice

Comment: What's wrong with your recursion? Btw. you should only create a `WebPage` object if you are adding it to the `Map`.

Comment: When I run the webcrawler I am parsing the same site more than once. For instance lets say I started the crawler at http://www.somewebsite.com/1 and then that website had a link to another site http://somewebsite.com/2 and then that site linked back to http://www.somewebsite.com/1 I do not want to parse the first website all over again, I simply need to skip it and move on. However, this is currently not the case.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code using the debugger? Doing this you will see why your comparison of the `linkUrl` might fail.

Comment: @NickHolt yes sorry. Just edited it.

Comment: @NickHolt my logic might be broken, but I am trying to add a webpage to a hashmap (that will hold all visited webpages) and then use the hashmap to prevent from revisiting pages. Any idea how this should look?

Comment: Please change System.out.println("Added webPage at " + webPage.getUrl()); to print linkUrl instead of getUrl() of the webpage object since you didn't show us that class. Also, you should trim the urls with .trim() if you do any sort of handling on them to avoid trailing spaces.

Comment: @Xabster just did, sorry about that

Comment: `linkUrl` appears to be a `String`, while your `containsKey` seems to be using an `Element`.

Comment: @Xabster yes it still prints identical results. I will post the edits

Comment: @BlueRidgeTigers you don't have to. Nick Holt gave you the answer. Your loop checks Element objects against the map's containsKey(). Element and String are not the same types.

Comment: @Xabster that solution did not work unfortunately

Comment: @BlueRidgeTigers I think you simply need to keep one list of visited pages starting with you root page.  When you visit a page  you check that it's not already in the list, if it's not you add the page to the list then parse it.  If you're parsing a lot of pages, you might have to optimise the check - maybe splitting the list by domain, etc.

Comment: @NickHolt that's what I am trying to do, for some reason though it is not working properly. It's quite frustrating

Comment: The trim thing needs to be linkUrl = linkUrk.trim();

Comment: @Xabster same results

Comment: @Xabster just uploaded it

Comment: Assuming the fix to the type in the key check solved the problem with the same link in a given page, then your problem is that the `Map`s are local to each instance of `WebPage`.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new map for each web-page. This will ensure that if the same link occurs on the page twice it will only be crawled once but it will not deal with the case where the same link appears on two different pages.

`https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/` appears on both `https://www.google.com/` and `https://www.google.com/services/`.

To avoid this use a single map throughout your crawl and pass it as a parameter into the recursion.

```
public class WebCrawler {

    private HashMap<String, WebPage> visited = new HashMap<String, WebPage>();

    public static void crawling(Map<String, WebPage> visited, WebPage webpage, int currentCrawlDepth, int maxCrawlDepth) {

    }
}
```

As you are also holding a map of the images etc you may prefer to create a new object, perhaps call it `visited`, and make it keep track.

```
public class Visited {

    private HashMap<String, WebPage> webPages = new HashMap<String, WebPage>();

    public boolean visit(String url, WebPage page) {
        if (webPages.containsKey(page)) {
            return false;
        }
        webPages.put(url, page);
        return true;
    }

    private HashMap<String, WebImage> webImages = new HashMap<String, WebImage>();

    public boolean visit(String url, WebImage image) {
        if (webImages.containsKey(image)) {
            return false;
        }
        webImages.put(url, image);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: @BlueRidgeTigers - See my additions.